# How do i add NSFunctionBarAPIEnabled to my project's plist?

Tags: objective-c, plist, macos-sierra

I do not want to support the touchbar for my Cocoa Application and so am adding the following code:

```
NSDictionary* myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"NSFunctionBarAPIEnabled"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:myDict];
```

If I add the same value NSFunctionBarAPIEnabled as a boolean type and set the value to NO in my plist it doesn't work.

I am using Xcode Version 8.2.1